# Ozonated oil Mixed with water.

Tags: ozone

I wish to emulsify ozonated oil with water and other ingredients to make a cream. Will mixing the ozone oil and water together with an emulsifier lessen the potency of the ozone oil as an oxidant? what if i were to ozonate the water and oil together and add an emulsifier at the end and blend them? with emulsifying wax for example.  THankyou!

Comment: LOL - Instead of *ozonated oil* use *snake oil*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this with a sota ozonator and it doesn't work out that well using water.  First when you ozonate oil by itself it gets really thick which clogs up your aerator for use with anything else so if you do this you have to use a separate aerator for oil and water.

I'm looking at doing something similar with bees wax and colloidal silver and placing the contents into a chap stick like container, when I figure something out I'll let you know.  Water can be mixed with oil with out using an emulsifier.  Dr Gerald Pollack from the University of Washington goes into what he calls the The Fourth Phase of Water "EZ water" and this type of water is known to mix with oil based substances. https://youtu.be/p9UC0chfXcg

His work can be found here
http://faculty.washington.edu/ghp/

Oil and water aren’t suppose to mix but they can see interview below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KQwh6j-uOg&feature=youtu.be&t=28m17s